# Is there a keyboard shortcut for stage lines in git gui?

Tags: git, user-interface, git-gui

In the standard [git gui](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gui), there are options to [stage selected lines](http://www.mfranc.com/uncategorized/git-git-gui-staging-selected-lines/) or stage hunk. I find myself using these options constantly, but each time I have to right click, which can be tricky on a touchy work laptop trackpad. Is there a keyboard shortcut for the 'stage selected lines' functionality?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a solution:

Open this file:

```
c:/Program Files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-gui.tcl
```

Add the following:

```
bind .   <$M1B-Key-d> stagelines

proc stagelines {} {
    apply_or_revert_range_or_line %X %Y 0
    # for older versions of git-gui, use this line instead:
    #apply_range_or_line %X %Y
    do_rescan
}
```

Restart git-gui

Now you can highlight the lines and hit CTRL-D to stage them.

Comment: I tried to do this on linux (file `/usr/lib/git-core/git-gui`), but as of today,
git-gui does not have a `proc` called `apply_range_or_line` anymore, so this does not work anymore.

Comment: maybe try this -   


instead of this:  


`apply_range_or_line $cursorX $cursorY`  



try this:  


`apply_or_revert_range_or_line $cursorX $cursorY 0`  

based on:

`https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/git/patch/20190828215725.13376-2-me@yadavpratyush.com/
    -       -command {apply_range_or_line $cursorX $cursorY; do_rescan}
    +       -command {apply_or_revert_range_or_line $cursorX $cursorY 0; do_rescan}`

sorry about formatting - i give up

Comment: :D I know the feeling (regarding formatting here).
Thank you, this line worked!
`apply_or_revert_range_or_line %X %Y 0`. Could you maybe update the answer, adding the new way, and optionally keepin the old one below? I could also do it if you prefer.